# How to set directory path using Xam.Plugin.Media.CrossMedia

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

While using the Xam.Plugin.Media.CrossMedia, i want to set the location of where the images go like this:

**/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com...App/files/Pictures/MYPICS/Updated/pic.png**

using the following code:

```
string innerDirectory = "Updated"; 
takePhoto.Clicked += async (sender, args) =>
            {

                try
                {

                    var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
                    {
                        Directory = "MYPICS//" + innerDirectory,
                        Name = "pic"+".jpg",
                        SaveToAlbum = false

                    });
    ...
```

Instead, this is the actual Directory path I get when the application executes:

**/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com...App/files/Pictures/*MYPICSUpdated*/pic.png**

It merges the Directory *MYPICS* with the directory *Updated*.

How can i set the directory "MYPICS" to have a sub-directory "Updated"?

Comment: You can specify a subfolder(s), but the root path is baked into the library.

Comment: @Jason To clarify, how would i go about specifying a sub folder?

Comment: `Directory = "some_folder_name"`